# Facebook server side oauth token

Tags: php, facebook, cron, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm updating a cron script made with the previous version of the php sdk for facebook (3.2.2). They way it was implemented it was using a fixed access token. My question is, is there a way to generate it on the server without asking the user to login? (since this is a cron I won't be able to show anything to the user anyways.

All the documentation I've seen so far points to browser based applications. How would I go about doing this server-side only? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out.

For those with the same question all you have to do is ask the sdk to start a new session using your app id and app secret as follows:

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($appId, $appSecret);
$session = FacebookSession::newAppSession(); //starts a new session using the previous info
```

Then try to validate it (used snippet from [the facebook documenation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookSession/4.0.0).

```
try {
// Try to validate the session:
    $session->validate();
} catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    // Session not valid, Graph API returned an exception with the reason.
    echo $ex->getMessage();
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
   // Graph API returned info, but it may mismatch the current app or have expired.
   echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```